# Sybase IQ and Encrypted Passwords

Tags: parameters, connection-string, sap-iq

I have need to use the ENP (Encrypted Password) parameter with Sybase 
IQ.  The documentation has a good reference on how to use it but not 
how to generate the password ... so how does one generate the 
encrypted password for use with the ENP connection parameter??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it's when you define the DSN in the ODBC Control Panel--or whatever other utility Sybase provides to define a connection on other platforms.  When the DSN is stored in file or the registry, you should see the ENP parameter defined rather than PWD.

And unless there's an asymmetric algorithm involved--with the private key definable by the sa--I wouldn't consider this to be better than obfuscation.  That is, lock down the capabilities of the user!

Answer (score 1):

hythlodayr is correct - the ODBC administrator creates the ENP parameter instead of the PWD parameter when you check the "encrypt password" checkbox. The iqdsn utility's -pe switch does the same thing if you create your DSNs that way.

The ENP parameter is encrypted using a proprietary encryption algorithm, but it is not a substitute for strong encryption. A determined hacker could probably break it. Any DSN that contains a password, encrypted or not, is a security risk.

*Full disclosure*: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering. SQL Anywhere is the database server used by Sybase IQ.

Comment: Well wow, nothing like getting the answer straight out of the horses mouth :)

Comment: We cannot use integrated security to login to the database (for various reasons, one being that our database is on Unix and we run our apps on Windows).  What would you recommend to improve security in this scenario?

Comment: Optimal security: AES encryption of the database file, where the encryption key is entered in a dialog box when the server starts (the -ep switch). TLS connection encryption. Passwords never stored in DSNs, though I understand that this last one can be quite inconvenient.

SA version 11.0 introduced Kerberos support. I don't know much about Kerberos, but I know it's supported on both Windows and Unix. Docs are here: http://snipurl.com/sa-kerberos (redirect to dcx.sybase.com)